# Schedule Sagemaker Notebooks Execution without using external Services

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I was looking for a solution, to execute a scheduled Sagemaker Jupyter Notebooks using Cron Jobs. However, due to access restrictions in my working environment, I cannot use any external services like Lambda, Cloudwatch, event bridge etc... I had tried to look around for solutions, but most of them had made use of external services. I am looking to see i can schedule it with only privilege of Sagemaker Notebook instances. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Find the sample here

[AWS sagemaker notebook cron sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/on-start.sh)